# Tab Pages (Signed_Request / OAuth 2.0 / SSL)

Tags: tabs, request, signed, facebook-oauth

I just wanted to make sure I understand the requirements of the upcoming October 1st deadline!  I know that canvas apps require using OAuth 2.0, I am just wondering if tab pages have to require it?  I am just building a fan gateway page and I'm using the signed_request to check if they like the page already, but I have no need for additional permissions, so is authentication/asking for app permissions even necessary?

Answer (score 1):

No, you will not need to worry about OAuth 2.0 if you aren't prompting for permissions. You will however need an SSL certificate for your fan page tab.